# How set dropdown value not change in localstorage after redirect or refresh in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Issue was after dropdown value selected as tamil or hindi that value need to pass next Page. My Page translated into selected Language. I set in session and Local storage. But when it redirect to other page it turns into undefined in local storage. I share my page. This is first Page I select Tamil.
[image]

And I select next page means It refresh and change into Undefined.

[image]

This is My function

```
handleChanges() {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  localStorage.setItem("myData", event.target.value);
  console.log("values", event.target.value);
  localStorage.getItem("myData");

  window.sessionStorage.setItem(
    "MyService.myObj",
    JSON.stringify(event.target.value)
  );

  let url =
    "http://XXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYZZZZ/Translate?values=OurStory,HowItWorks,Blog,Login,BeaParopakari,Welcome,Username,Password,ContactUs,TermsandConditions,SignUp,Forgotpassword?&lang=" +
    event.target.value;
  let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  const accessToken = user;
  console.log(accessToken);
  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Request-Headers ",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        Details: data,
      });
      console.log("Filter", data);
      const longArray = data;
      const size = 1;
    });
}
```

Please share your Knowledge. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: are you getting value on console?

Comment: Yes in console it print using "event.target.value" but in next page it shows undefined @Rahul

Comment: In console it works @RahulSharma